# I have dataframe. I need to create a dictionary with row as the key and columns which has 'True' as the values of the dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

```
     0    1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9  
3  False   True  False   True   True  False   True   True   True  False      
4  False   True  False   True   True   True   True   True  False  False
```

I need to create something like this

dict= {3: [1,3,4,6,7,8], 4: [0,1,3,4,5,6,7]}

Comment: I don't understand, don't you mean the columns as the dictionary keys? Every row in a pandas dataframe is part of every column, so there is no point showing which columns it is a part of.

Comment: The key will be the row value.

Comment: oh now i understand

Comment: i deleted my post because andrej kesely has addressed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
out = dict(
    df.apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i, v in zip(x.index, x) if v], axis=1)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{3: [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8], 4: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
```